# LAN8720A - PoE Protection

Tags: ethernet, poe, phy, lan8720

I will go straight to my question.
I have currently a PoE PD using LAN8720A PHY,
i follow almost all manufacturer recommendations on PCB layout and schematics, anyways i have dead LAN8720A straight away or after some time(2 weeks - 3 months).
After reading [Microchip AN2157](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ApplicationNotes/ApplicationNotes/00002157B.pdf) i added the Minimum TVS Bidirectional Protection Diode: DBI with model number: [CDSOD323-T03C](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_BOURNS-CDSOD323-T03C_C711705.pdf) between PHY and Transformer but situation didn't change so much, of course amount of devices what die reduced, but didn't disappear completely (always happens on Ubiquity PoE Switches).

[image]
[image]

Is anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have been involved with a product using the DP1435 module in the past, and must confess I am not a fan.    My experience was that the built in filtering and noise/spike suppression in the POE converter is "limited", with very significant direct coupling of line transients to the internal "isolated" power supply.  This in turn caused massive field reliability issues,  killing not just the PHYs, but also a separate PLL on the delivered device.

This issue is to some degree recognized by the manufacturer, with the datasheet for the 12V version calling out the following filtering circuit for "lower ripple and noise". [image].

I got the design updated to use a Murata [module](https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/power/campaign/dcdc), and we have since seen zero field failures.  The Murata unit is more expensive in terms of straight BOM cost, but when considering the total cost including field replacement, reputation damage, and investigation time, it is much better value in our application.

(This may or may not be your issue, but I thought it worth sharing.)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience with this module.
I will try to implement this LC filter and see how is going, for me now is more important PHY protection on RX & TX lines.